# differences between lapply(list) and "for"-loop

Tags: r

Recently I wrote a piece of code which did not behave as expected.
In a loop over two dataframes df1, df2 I tried to collect data in a matrix "a"...:

```
df1=data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(10,20))
df2=data.frame(x=c(4,5),y=c(40,50))
dlist <- list(df1,df2)

a <- c(0,"...creation...")
a <- rbind(a, c(0,"rbind test OK"))

lapply(dlist, function(d) {
   print(paste("x",d$x[1]))
   a <- rbind(a, c(d$x[1],"data copied"))
   })

a <- rbind(a, c(0,"rbind test 2 OK"))
```

Inspecting "a" after executing these lines yields

```
a
  [,1] [,2]             
a "0"  "...creation..." 
  "0"  "rbind test OK"  
  "0"  "rbind test 2 OK"
```

That is, the rbind-statement inside the lapply-loop was not executed.

Expected output is:

```
a 
  [,1] [,2] 
a "0"  "...creation..." 
  "0"  "rbind test OK" 
  "1"  "data copied" 
  "4"  "data copied" 
  "0"  "rbind test 2 OK"
```

Why is that?

Comment: One difference is that a for-loop uses the same environment where it was called; lapply (and other functions like that) use their own environment, just like other functions do. That means that `a` that you've defined in `lapply()` function is different from `a` that you've defined earlier. Please provide an example of your expected output if you want more info

Comment: expected output would be
> a
  [,1] [,2]             
a "0"  "...creation..." 
  "0"  "rbind test OK"  
  "1"  "data copied"
  "4"  "data copied"
  "0"  "rbind test 2 OK"

Comment: Please edit your question to include the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the environment **outside** the loop with operator `<<-`, but this is a quite improper imperative programming reflexe:

```
lapply(dlist, function(d) {
   print(paste("x",d$x[1]))
   a <<- rbind(a, c(d$x[1],"data copied"))
})
```

A proper way would be to proceed like:

```
res = do.call(rbind, lapply(dlist, function(d) c(d$x[1],"data copied")))

a = rbind(a, res, c(0,"rbind test 2 OK"))

#  [,1] [,2]             
#a "0"  "...creation..."  
#  "0"  "rbind test OK"  
#  "1"  "data copied"    
#  "4"  "data copied"    
#  "0"  "rbind test 2 OK"
```